# Create relationship in neo4j if does not exist, update property value if exists

Tags: neo4j, merge, cypher

I have a node with three properties, say something created like

```
create (a:item{type:'detergent', weight:'500g', 'quantity':322})
```

And another node like

```
create (b:customer{id:'933B3'})
```

A relationship with property `count` should exist from node `a` to node `b`.

I want to create the relationship with `count = 1` if the relationship does not already exist otherwise update its count value by adding 1 to it, something like `set relationship.count = relationship.count + 1`

I can use `MERGE`, along with `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` for this purpose. However, here is the problem:
The MERGE matches whole pattern whereas I want to match only two properties of node a rather than all three.

Therefore, technically I want to create a relationship between

`a:item{type:'detergent', weight:'500g'}` and `b:customer{id:'933B3'}`

This means, all the nodes with **label = item**, **type = detergent** and **weight = 500g** should have a relationship with customer of **id = 933B3** irrespective of the quantity of the detergent.

If I use MERGE on two properties of node a, it will not create a relationship between existing item node(which has 3 properties) and customer node, it will rather create new nodes with properties specified in MERGE. As mentioned above, I also need to update the count property if relationship is found to be already existing.

How can I match selected properties of already existing nodes to create relationship between existing nodes with initializing property value, and otherwise update the property value of relationship already exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use MERGE, you do not have to specify all properties of the node. MERGE is like a MATCH and if no matches are found then a CREATE. There are definitely :item nodes with those properties, and it doesn't matter if there are additional properties beyond what you specify in the MERGE.

This should work for you:

```
MERGE (a:item{type:'detergent', weight:'500g'})
MERGE (b:customer{id:'933B3'})
MERGE (a)-[r:REL]->(b) // replace with your actual relationship type
ON CREATE SET r.count = 1
ON MATCH SET r.count = r.count + 1
```

Comment: Perfect..! This is something I was looking for. I learn that the key is to use MERGE on all entities rather than just on the pattern.

Comment: MERGE can be tricky. Check out this [knowledge base article on how MERGE works](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/) to better understand is behavior.